# Changing image while clicking button in html/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sockets

Please i want to change the temperature level in each button click. In a way to have a white arrow in a first time, two white arrow i a seconde time .... i have images withe 1 arrow, 2 arrow ext.

[image]

this my image in html :

```
   <div id="WBR"><img src="assets/AWImages/V0.png"></div>
   <button  id= "HI"   class="circle" >+</button>
```

I simulate the button click in javascript like this :

```
let addb = document.querySelector('#HI');
addb.addEventListener('click', () =>{
input.value = parseInt(input.value)+1;
if((input.value)<5)
{
socket.emit('Value of hum changed',input.value);
}
else
{
input.value =4;
}
});
```

I really appreciate ur help ;)

Comment: I'm not quite following what the question is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let addb = document.querySelector('#WBR');
let wbr = document.querySelector('#HI');
var f = document.querySelector('#f');
var Score = 0;
var win = 5;
var gameOver = false;

addb.addEventListener("click", function () {
  if (!gameOver) {
        Score++ ;
          if (Score == win) {
          gameOver = true;
          addb.style.color = "green";
  }
    f.innerHTML = Score;
  }
});
```

```html
 <div id="WBR"><img src="assets/AWImages/V0.png"></div>
   <button  id= "HI"   class="circle" >+</button>
   <p id="f">0</p>
```

Comment: Thank u so much for your response i really appreciate it's verry helpfull